# Salesforce - Calculate case age in business days based on whether it is closed or in a specific state

Tags: salesforce, formula

I am trying to create a formula that can tell me the age of a case in business days if it's open, closed, or in a specific status. This is what I've got so far:

```
IF(OR(IsNull(ClosedDate), IsNull(Waiting_Confirmation_Date__c)),

(
    5*FLOOR((TODAY()-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) + 
    MIN(5, MOD(TODAY()-DATE(1996,01,01), 7))
) - (
    5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) + 
    MIN(5, MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01), 7))
),

IF(NOT(IsNull(Waiting_Confirmation_Date__c)),
(
    5*FLOOR((Waiting_Confirmation_Date__c - DATE(1996,01,01))/7) + 
    MIN(5, MOD(Waiting_Confirmation_Date__c - DATE(1996,01,01), 7))
) - (
    5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) + 
    MIN(5, MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01), 7))
),

(
    5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(ClosedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) + 
    MIN(5, MOD(DATEVALUE(ClosedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01), 7))
) - (
    5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) + 
    MIN(5, MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01), 7))
))


)
```

I set the Waiting_Confirmation_Date__c with a workflow that specifies today's date when a user sets the case to a specific status. Basically what I am trying to do is this:

If the case is not closed, or not in Awaiting Confirmation (where the "Waiting_Confirmation_Date__c" would be set) to set the business age to the age from when it was created to today.

Else if the "Waiting_Confirmation_Date__c" is set, make the age time between when it was created to the confirmation date.

Lastly if it is closed set it to the age from when it was created to when it was closed.

I think just my if/else is wrong somehow, but I am going cross-eyed trying to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, there is an extra Salesforce forum on the Stackexchange: salesforce.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The solution was this, thanks guys:

```
IF(AND(IsClosed),

(
5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(ClosedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) +
MIN(5, MOD(DATEVALUE(ClosedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01), 7))
) - (
5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) +
MIN(5, MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01), 7))
),

IF(NOT(IsNull(Waiting_Confirmation_Date__c)),
(
5*FLOOR((Waiting_Confirmation_Date__c - DATE(1996,01,01))/7) +
MIN(5, MOD(Waiting_Confirmation_Date__c - DATE(1996,01,01), 7))
) - (
5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) +
MIN(5, MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01), 7))
),

(
5*FLOOR((TODAY()-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) +
MIN(5, MOD(TODAY()-DATE(1996,01,01), 7))
) - (
5*FLOOR((DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01))/7) +
MIN(5, MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)-DATE(1996,01,01), 7))
)))
```